# Jsp form post pass an empty object to Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In current controller i fill my userWrapper with collection of Users who haven't access to use application and send it as attribute to jsp where it will render.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/cockpit")
    public String cockpit(Model model, UserWrapper receivedUserWrapper) {
        siftOutEnabled(receivedUserWrapper);

        try {
            List<User> users = userService.findAllUsersWhoNotAccepted();
            UserWrapper userWrapper = new UserWrapper();
            userWrapper.setUsers(users);
            model.addAttribute("wrapper", userWrapper);
            model.addAttribute("users", userWrapper.getUsers());
        } catch (UsersNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return "cockpit";
    }
```

in jsp exists checkboxes which binded with User objects of UserWrapper collection users. my jsp page look like:

```
<form:form method="POST" commandName="wrapper" action="cockpit">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>mail</th>
                <th>pass</th>
                <th>registrationDate</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user" varStatus="loop">
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.id}</td>
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.password}</td>
                    <td>${user.registrationDate}</td>
                    <td><form:checkbox path="users[${loop.index}].enabled" />
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form:form>
```

this jsp page render proper result:

```
id  mail    pass    registrationDate    
1   market@test.ra  pass    2016-02-02 21:46:40.0   
2   tara@ra.ra  passwd  2016-02-03 20:37:18.0
```

near every line exists checbox, when I check some lines, and send post to controller, there i catch only these values? checkboxes work.

```
[User [id=0, email=null, password=null, enabled=true], 
User [id=0, email=null, password=null, enabled=false]]
```

why the values null or 0? 
Here is my UserWrapper class, and User consrtuctor:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
...
public User(long id, String email, String password, Date registrationDate, boolean enabled) {
        this.setEmail(email);
        this.setPassword(password);
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
        this.setEnabled(enabled);
        roles = new HashSet<>();
    }
...
}

public class UserWrapper {

    private boolean checked;
    private List<User> users;

...
}
```

**UPDATE**
I would also ask: how send object from controller to jsp, change that object there and then send back this already changed object to controller...

**UPDATE**

```
public class SpringMvcIntializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { ApplicationConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] { WebMvcConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in your jsp code, there are is only checkbox which sends the form data in name and value pair. Hence you get only values for checkbox. Try updating your jsp as follows.

```
<td>${user.id}<input type="hidden" name="users[${loop.index}].id" value="${user.id}"/></td>
<td>${user.email}<input type="hidden" name="users[${loop.index}].email" value="${user.email}"/></td>
<td>${user.password}<input type="hidden" name="users[${loop.index}].password" value="${user.password}"/></td>
<td>${user.registrationDate}<input type="hidden" name="users[${loop.index}].registrationDate" value="${user.registrationDate}"/></td>
<td><form:checkbox path="users[${loop.index}].enabled" />
```

**Edited**

For dates you need CustomDateEditor registered in your controller class as:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    CustomDateEditor editor = new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"), true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, editor);
}
```

Comment: also question how to pass that date to controller ??